# Would frequency be considered a variable?

Tags: statistics

I guess the best way to ask this question is a with a scenario.

> Jim works at the local bowls club that has their own version of the 'Lotto'. There are $10$ balls in a barrel from which Jim draws. Each 'Lotto' draw involves Jim picking $5$ balls from the barrel without replacement. After $5$ draws Jim observes the following;
>
> - Balls $1,2,9$ four times each.
> - Balls $3,5,6,7,8, 5, 4$ five times each.
> - Ball $10$ three times.

My question is, can frequency be considered a variable? That is, can the frequency of the number of balls be considered a variable? My guess is no, but I'm not entirely sure.

My reasoning is that since the unit in the scenario is the 'Lotto' draw itself, the only information you can take from a single draw is the ball number, therefore, frequency cannot be considered a variable.

Does this hold in general too? Since frequency is really the number of times you observe a particular variable, it can't be considered a variable in and of itself?

Answer (score 1):

It absolutely can. Anything that could be a measured outcome of an event or series of events is a variable of the system. The average of a number of measurements is also a variable. The standard deviation of those measurements is another variable.